# onClick change list styles

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

Let's say I have a simple list:

```
  <ul>
    <li class="notClicked">1</li>
    <li class="notClicked">2</li>
    <li class="notClicked">3</li>
  </ul>
```

Can I onClick of one "li" change styles of all `li`'s except the one clicked?

So if I click "li" number 2, then the list will look like:

```
  <ul>
    <li class="notClicked">1</li>
    <li class="clicked">2</li>
    <li class="notClicked">3</li>
  </ul>
```

So if I click on first "li" then it will have clicked class, while others will be notClicked.

In case you want to play with it, here's jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ucuca4/edit

Make either in [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework) or plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            /*<![CDATA[*/
            var Lst;

            function CngClass(obj){
             if (Lst) Lst.className='';
             obj.className='Clicked';
             Lst=obj;
            }

            /*]]>*/
        </script>
        <style>
            .notClicked {color: black}
            .Clicked {color: red}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#" class="notClicked">1
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#"  class="notClicked">2
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#"  class="notClicked">3
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why change the style of the other? You may want to change the style of the clicked element.

If so, you can use jQuery for that

Example:

```
<li class = "notClicked">element 1</li>
<li class = "notClicked">element 2</li>
<li class = "notClicked">element 3</li>

$('.notClicked').click(function()
{
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: because I need to change others too :)

Comment: So you want the others to have a different class also when an element is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function changeClass(){
        document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("class", "Clicked");
    }
</script>

<ul>
    <li class="notClicked" >1</li>
    <li class="notClicked" onClick="changeClass()" id="idElement">2</li>
    <li class="notClicked">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Changing class using the setAttribute method is not supported in Internet Explorer 7 and below. Always work with className DOM attribute.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: I saw you love to format question and answer good great way.