# onClick change list styles *but

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

Following up from the last question answered: [onClick change list styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477541/onclick-change-list-styles)

Instead of changing all classes, change all classes but "li's" with a particular class. So if one of the li's has a class name of `dontChange` the its class name won't be change but all others will.

> When you click an item it should be changed to "clicked" all other items but the item with "dontChange" to "notClicked". When you doubleclick a "clicked" or "notClicked" item it should change to "dontChange" and everything else should change to "notClicked".

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
var Lst;

function CngClass(obj){
 if (Lst) Lst.className='';
 if(obj.className=='dontChange')
 {
     obj.className='dontChange';
 }
 else
 {
 obj.className='Clicked';
 Lst=obj;
 }

}

/*]]>*/
</script>
<style>
  .notClicked {color: black}
  .Clicked {color: red}
  .dontChange {color: blue}

</style></head>

<body>

<ul>  
<li>
<a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#" class="notClicked">Test 1
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#"  class="notClicked">Test 2
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#"  class="dontChange">Test 3
</a>
</li>  
</ul>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work with my modification, please take a look at (class=playItem is the one I want to hold): http://jsbin.com/abedi5/edit

Comment: i think problem is when working on double click it also call the onclick event...

Comment: can u explain more about wat exactly you want

Comment: when you click an item it should be changed to "clicked" all other items but the item with "dontChange" to "notClicked". When you doubleclick a "clicked" or "notClicked" item it should change to "dontChange" and everything else should change to "notClicked"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out jQuery. You could write a selector like this to add a class to all `li`s that don't have the class `dontChange`.

```
$('li').not('.dontChange').addClass('changed');
```

Answer (score 0):

using the code from the previous answer you'll want to change it to something like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var Lst;

function CngClass(obj){
 if(obj.className=='notClicked')
 {  obj.className='Clicked';
    Lst=obj;
 }
}

</script>
<style>
  .notClicked .dontChange{color: black}
  .Clicked {color: red}
</style></head>

<body>

<ul>
<li>
<a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#" class="dontChange">1
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#"  class="notClicked">2
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#"  class="notClicked">3
</a>
</li>
</ul>

</body>


</html>
```

This simply says that if it is a particular class then change it.

tested in FF3.61