# Change color of ul on double click

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, dom-events

Is there any way that we can change or **highlight the color or the certain row of ul tag** on its double click event?

```
<c:forEach var="food" varStatus="i" items="${foodList}">
    <c:set var="foodInfo" value="${food.key}"/> 
        <ul class="scroller_result" ondblclick="showDetails('${foodInfo}','m','iPad');"">
            <li> <input type="checkbox" name="foodIds" <option value="${food.key}"><c:out value="${food.value}"/></option>>
            </li>
        </ul>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery` would be really elegant solution

```
function showDetails(...) {
   ... 
   $(".scroller_result").css("color","red");
}
```

You can import `jQuery` by adding to your page

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Look [example](http://jsfiddle.net/HpGBj/) at `jsfiddle`

---

If you do not want to use external JS libraries, you could do it using pure JS.
Look at my expanded [example](http://cdpn.io/joebh).

Comment: This doesn't fire specifically on double-click

Comment: @MichaelPeterson look at example

Answer (score 1):

You should find the hint and answer by looking into similar issue

[onClick change list styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477541/onclick-change-list-styles)